# How to get 32-bit integer texture working in WebGL 2.0

Tags: glsles, webgl2

I am trying to create an integer texture with 32-bits Red channel in WebGL 2.0:

```
this.kdTreeTextureSize = Math.ceil(Math.sqrt(numberOfKdNodes));
this.kdTreeData = new Int32Array(this.kdTreeTextureSize * this.kdTreeTextureSize);
this.kdTree.fillDataArray(this.kdTreeData);
this.kdTreeTexture = gl.createTexture();
gl.activeTexture(gl.TEXTURE3);
gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, this.kdTreeTexture);
gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, gl.NEAREST);
gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, gl.NEAREST);
gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_WRAP_S, gl.CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_WRAP_T, gl.CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
gl.texImage2D(gl.TEXTURE_2D, 0, gl.R32I, this.kdTreeTextureSize, this.kdTreeTextureSize, 0, gl.RED_INTEGER, gl.INT, this.kdTreeData);
```

and read it in GLES 3.0 fragment shader:

```
int(texture(kdTreeTexture, getTexCoord(0, kdTreeTextureSize))
```

getTexCoord function:

```
vec2 getTexCoord(int i, float textureSize) {
    return vec2(
        (mod(float(i), float(textureSize)) + 0.5) / textureSize, 
        (float(i / int(textureSize)) + 0.5) / textureSize
    );
}
```

I set the value of the first pixel as **1073741824**, i.e., 2^30, but I get the wrong value of **1100730680** when reading it in the fragment shader. What is the issue here? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Got it working. I forgot to do:

```
gl.uniform1i(gl.getUniformLocation(this.tracerProgram, "kdTreeTexture"), 3);
gl.uniform1i(gl.getUniformLocation(this.tracerProgram, "kdLeavesTexture"), 4);
```

Comment: Just FYI but your code would probably be more performant if you look up your uniform locations at init time.